# MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an error. The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection Zonedetails shown  below. below.

I am using C# to Insert or Update a Unit to Units array. If it is an insert  I can insert Area blank. If it is an update It should only update the UnitName.

```
{ 
    "Code" : "Zone1", 
    "Name" : "ZoneName1", 
    "Units" : [
        {
            "UnitCode" : "Unitcode1", 
            "UnitName" : "UnitCodeName", 
            "Areas" : [
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCode1", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "Code" : "Zone2", 
    "Name" : "ZoneName2", 
    "Units" : [
        {
            "UnitCode" : "UnitCode2", 
            "UnitName" : "UnityName2", 
            "Areas" : [
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "Areacode2", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "Code" : "Zone3", 
    "Name" : "ZoneName3", 
    "Units" : [
        {
            "UnitCode" : "UnitCode3", 
            "UnitName" : "UnitName3", 
            "Areas" : [
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "Areadcode3", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName3"
                }, 
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCode4", 
                    "AreaName" : "Areaname4"
                }, 
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCode5", 
                    "AreaName" : "Areaname5"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "UnitCode" : "UnitCode6", 
            "UnitName" : "UnitName6", 
            "Areas" : [
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCode10", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName10"
                }, 
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCOde11", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName10"
                }, 
                {
                    "AreaCode" : "AreaCode12", 
                    "AreaName" : "AreaName12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have writtent a C# code shown below. But getting "***The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query***"error if the Unit Code does not exist. Added not before unitCode check.

```
    var mongoCollection = _context.GetCollection<Zone>("ZoneDetail");
    var filter = Builders<Zone>.Filter.Where(x => x.Code == zoneCode && !x.Units.Any(u => u.UnitCode == unit.UnitCode));
    var updateUnitCode = Builders<Zone>.Update.Set(x => x.Units.ElementAt(-1).UnitCode, unit.UnitCode);
    var updateUnitName = Builders<Zone>.Update.Set(x => x.Units.ElementAt(-1).UnitName, unit.UnitName);
    var result = await mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, Builders<Zone>.Update.Combine(updateUnitCode, updateUnitName), new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggest that filter is not able to find matching element.

Either try to change your input or change your filter criteria.

Comment: Yes You are right. I want insert into that array if UnitCode not found. How to achieve that . For that only I enabled IsUpsert = true

Comment: You need to put not before your condition for unitcode check like this   !x.Units.Any(u => u.UnitCode == unit.UnitCode)

Comment: paramar Can you please update the C# code. So that I can have a clear understanding of your suggestion.

Comment: I think insert or update will only work with Id, if ID exist then it will update otherwise it will insert. It will not work the way you are trying.